# Como passar Imagem por imagem para adicionar ao banco de dados?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando adicionar imagem ao banco de dados, como faço para adicionar temporariamente objeto por objeto em up, variando o objeto de acordo com índice que tiver em upload? como tentei fazer  na linha 7

**Sei que há inconsistências no código abaixo, estou tentando ver como adicionar as imagens uma a uma, e depois tento resolver o resto**

**eu ainda não consertei todo o código a parte relevante da linha 4 até 9**

### Controller

```
       [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ImagemId,Image,ImagemTipo")]Imagem imagem,List <HttpPostedFileBase> upload)
    {
        List<Imagem> todasImagens;
        int contado = upload.Count;
        for (int x = 0; x < upload.Count;) {
         //parte que eu nao sei como fazer 
         HttpPostedFileBase up = uploa;


        }
        if(upload != null && upload.Count> 0) {
            var arqImagem = new Imagem
            {
                ImagemTipo = upload.ContentType
            };
            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(upload.InputStream))
            {
                arqImagem.Imagem = reader.ReadBytes(upload.ContentLength);
            }
            imagem.Imagem = arqImagem.Imagem;
            imagem.ImagemTipo = arqImagem.ImagemTipo;
        }

             db.Imagens.Add(imagem);
            db.SaveChanges();
        return View(imagem);
    }
```

Comment: O código está incompleto amigo. Onde está a parte da consistência no BD? Se possível coloque também a classe Cliente.

Comment: não consegui entender qual é a sua dúvida e qual é o erro que está obtendo... o `if` não deveria estar dentro do form e por que você armazena cada arquivo no `up` e não utiliza em lugar nenhum?]

Comment: Leandro, referente ao up... foi uma tentativa de resolver, deixei pra mostrar que nao consegui.... mas o objetivo e por temporariamente em up, e subir um por um no banco de dados, entendeu?